# Is is possible to programmatically clear the console history?

Tags: c#, console, console-application

When working with a console application, a history of everything that has been entered at a `Console.ReadLine()` is stored. When at a console prompt to enter something, pressing the up/down cursor will scroll through this history (and the whole history can be viewed by pressing F7).

Using C#, is there are way to either disable this behaviour or clear the history of what has already been entered?

---

To clarify, `Console.Clear()` does not clear the history, only the screen buffer. I want to clear the command history.

---

**EDIT:** Having tried several of the suggested methods, as well as some of my own devising, the best approach is the one suggested by ho1. It is not ideal because it brings up another console window, but it does clear the history.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: Removed incorrect answer (I got confused about what you wanted to do) and added another (hopefully) better answer.

It might be possible to do this by freeing the current console using [FreeConsole](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683150%28VS.85%29.aspx) and then allocating a new console using [AllocConsole](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms681944%28VS.85%29.aspx). I'd assume that it wouldn't keep the command line history then.

In general, if you want to do things with the Console that's not supported by the .Net Framework, this MSDN page is a good place to look: [Console Functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682073%28VS.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Doesn't do anything to the history I'm afraid.

Comment: @adrianbanks: Yep, got confused about what you were doing (though at least I made a different mistake than the other answers to this question :)). I've updated my answer with another possible solution.

Answer (score 4):

Could this post on [How can I configure the command line history, DOSKEY?](http://www.windowsitpro.com/article/john-savills-windows-faqs/how-can-i-configure-the-command-line-history-doskey-.aspx) help?

> In olden DOS days a utility was available, DOSKEY.EXE, which enabled the user to cycle through previous commands. In NT this is enabled by default and you can cycle through old commands however DOSKEY has other abilities.
>
> To clear the current command line history use command:
>
> ```
> doskey /reinstall
> ```
>
> You can also optionally tell it how many old commands to keep with the /listsize parameter
>
> ```
> doskey /reinstall /listsize=50
> ```
>
> would keep 50 old commands.

Please let me know if it works and how you used it :)

Comment: I want to do this programmatically from within my own console application, so I do not want to have to rely on using an external tool.

Comment: What if the functionality you are looking to suppress is provided by that same tool?

Comment: @Svish: I've tried to call out to this from within my code, but it has no effect because it is launched in a separate console. It appears that I need to do this within code to get it to apply to the **current** console.

Comment: @adrianbanks - Right... Yeah, I thought you might. How did you call out to it? Is there a way to find out what the command does in the background? Like I think @Paul-Jan is referring to

Comment: @Svish: Ok, I'm a bit confused now! I called out to doskey by starting a new process. How else can I call out to it from C#?

Comment: @adrianbanks - Have a look at the `Start` method that takes a `ProcessStartInfo` class. For example there is two properties called `CreateNoWindow` and `UseShellExecute`. Maybe they can help with something? - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.aspx

Comment: @Svish: Yeah, already tried that with no joy. I cannot see how launching doskey will work as it will always be a new process.

Comment: @adrianbanks - Well, I was thinking that it is a new process when you run it from a standard console too. But anyways, seems like you hvave found a working solution =)

Answer (score 2):

This code is working for me to clear the command history. Limited testing and no guarantees on portability.

```
public static partial class ConsoleEx
{
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    static extern bool SetConsoleHistoryInfo(CONSOLE_HISTORY_INFO ConsoleHistoryInfo);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    static extern bool GetConsoleHistoryInfo(CONSOLE_HISTORY_INFO ConsoleHistoryInfo);

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    private class CONSOLE_HISTORY_INFO
    {
        public uint cbSize;
        public uint BufferSize;
        public uint BufferCount;
        public uint TrimDuplicates;
    }

    public static void ClearConsoleHistory()
    {
        var chi = new CONSOLE_HISTORY_INFO();
        chi.cbSize = (uint)System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(CONSOLE_HISTORY_INFO));

        if (!GetConsoleHistoryInfo(chi))
        {
            return;
        }

        var originalBufferSize = chi.BufferSize;
        chi.BufferSize = 0;

        if (!SetConsoleHistoryInfo(chi))
        {
            return;
        }

        chi.BufferSize = originalBufferSize;

        if (!SetConsoleHistoryInfo(chi))
        {
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Error handling removed and replaced with returns to improve readability of the concept example.

Comment: This should be the correct answer. It is C# .NET managed code which wraps the Win32 calls to accomplish what you need. Wrapper code like this is necessary to reach Win32 console functionality programmatically, like toggling EOL wrap, centering the console on the screen, locking window update, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [SetConsoleHistoryInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686031.aspx). According to the documentation it only works on Vista and above, so I'm not sure if it will help you or not.

Answer (score 0):

It seems according to MSN (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ie/library/system.console_members.aspx) the method `console.clear()` "Clears the console buffer .."

Comment: He wants to clear the command history, not the console buffer (if I understood correctly)

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the property

```
Console.BufferHeight : "This property defines the number of rows (or lines) stored in the buffer that is accessed by a console mode window"
```

Comment: I already tried that, but it will not let me set a value of zero.

Comment: BufferHeight is the scrollable window of all console output.  That's why there's also BufferWidth.