# Clear Console Command History C#

Tags: c#, windows, security, console, command

I'm writing some software which is password protected. When the user starts the program, they enter a password (which is blacked out when typing it). Then the program changes to a command line interface.

The problem is, you can scroll through command history, including the entered password in plaintext. How can I clear console history programmatically?

I've attempted the solutions found in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3244976/is-is-possible-to-programmatically-clear-the-console-history).

After trying Svish's answer on [the same post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3245023), it simply did not work. I used `Process.Start("doskey","/reinstall")` and all it did was open a command prompt window.

[Hans Olsson's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3245269/563532) answer didn't work either; I got an `AccessViolation`, and there is no good explanation on how to use it. Trying to use `FreeConsole` doesn't work either, because after freeing and reallocating I can no longer use `Console.WriteLine`. I get an `IOException: The method is not supported.`

Comment: Sadly, that did not work very well. Could not find any good explanations on how exactly to use it.

Comment: Which answer doesn't work well? Have you tried them all? In particular, Svish's answer? If they truly don't work, could you please edit your post to explain why in particular those answers don't work for you? If it's really not a duplicate, it can be reopened.

Comment: Edited to prove not duplicate.

Comment: I've tidied up the question and reopened it

Comment: I'm assuming you've tried using Console.Clear()?

Comment: I have tried using Console.Clear(), yes. It clears the screen, not the history, sadly

Comment: Try pressing Alt+F7 and see if you can clear it manually that way.  If it works, I'll try and write up an answer of how to do it in the program

Comment: That worked, actually. Can you write a program to send a certain keystroke to the program?

Comment: Yup, the two way I know how to do it are either by sending the keystrokes through Process.SendInput() or using test automation software.  Writing up an answer now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up changing the authentication method. It now retrieves the unique serial number of the BIOS/Motherboard. The serial numbers are now on a secure server and are retrieved by the program. If the serial is found then the execution will continue. If not, the execution will halt.

If people in the company need access to the program, they'll run the program, get access denied (with the serial number in the "access denied" statement), give the admin the serial number, and they'll put it in the system.

Answer (score 0):

Sending the keystrokes Alt+F7 to the console will clear it per [this](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-keyboard.html) documentation.  You can automate the sending of these keystrokes by using test automation software built into visual studio:

```
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting;

    Keyboard.SendKeys("%{F7}")
```

Comment: Where do you get the `Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting` import from? I dont see it in the references list -- also, since this is a testing import, would it be safe for final production?

Comment: Found the import.

Comment: The import doesn't seem to be working -- even after referencing it, `Keyboard.SendKeys` doesn't show up as a method. It does not exist in the current context.

Comment: @noodles You have the entire sequence of classes up to the method SendKeys() functional, right (e.g TestTools.UITesting both work)?

Comment: actually, i can only find the extension imports, e.g. `Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.Extension`

Comment: @noodles Hmm, try using this library instead: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @noodles Copy pasting this text "SendKeys.Send("%{F7}");" in should also have visual studio suggest the quick action of adding in System.Windows.Forms();

Comment: `System.InvalidOperationException occurred
  SendKeys cannot run inside this application because the application is not handling Windows messages.  Either change the application to handle messages, or use the SendKeys.SendWait method.`

Comment: @noodles I can't say I've had experience with either of those issues.  See if you can get this library to work; worst case it is open source and you can just poach the sendkeys methods from it.  


http://inputsimulator.codeplex.com/



Further, to answer your first question, all I can say is presumably.  There is nothing in testing software that should be fundamentally different than any other kind, and items like Selenium are often used for both scripting and testing.  If you are worried about it though, I'd suggest getting final approval from whoever's liable if something breaks.

Comment: Looks like System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.SendWait will work, as suggested by the error message, lmao

Comment: It says that ALT is not a valid keycode, though `Keyword "ALT" is not valid.` My code is the following: `SendKeys.SendWait("{ALT}+{F7}")`

Comment: `An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll
Keyword "ALT" is not valid.`

Comment: @noodles Ahh, I see the problem.  Instead of doing "{ALT}+{F7}", do "%{F7}"

Comment: @noodles if you are still having the problem, try the SendKeys("%{F7}") portion using inputsimulator.  I think what happened is SendWait() is trying to send to the program indefinitely, so it doesn't succeed nor error.