# In Ubuntu, how can I clear console history with C#?

Tags: c#, ubuntu, console, console-application

I am new to c #. I am creating a simple console application. my task is to make a mark in a certain place in the console. and erase the old position every time. It works. But there was a problem. When using console.clear (); there is simply a transfer to a new frame with the ability to view the old position of my previously marked point.

scrolling occurs after each click

how to remove previous console values?

MyCode:

```
using System;
    
    namespace paint
    {
        class Point
        {
            public int x {get;set;}
            public int y {get;set;}
    //public int mark_y {get;set;}
    //public int mark_x {get;set;}

            protected int[] Position(){
                this.x = x;
                this.y = y;
                //this.mark_x = mark_x;
                //this.mark_y = mark_y;
                return new int [] {this.x,this.y};
            }
        }
        class Program 
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                Point position = new Point{x = 10, y = 5};
                do
                {
                    Console.SetCursorPosition(position.x, position.y);
                    System.ConsoleKeyInfo console_key = Console.ReadKey(true);
                    if(console_key.Key == ConsoleKey.DownArrow && position.y >= 0 && position.y <= 9){
                        position.y += 1;
                    }
                    if(console_key.Key == ConsoleKey.UpArrow && position.y <= 10 && position.y >= 2){
                        position.y -= 1;
                    }
                    if(console_key.Key == ConsoleKey.LeftArrow && position.x <= 19 && position.x >= 1){
                        position.x -= 1;
                    }
                    if(console_key.Key == ConsoleKey.RightArrow && position.x >= 0 && position.x <= 18){
                        position.x += 1;
                    }
                    if(console_key.Key == ConsoleKey.Spacebar){
                        //position.mark_x = position.x;
                        //position.mark_y = position.y;
                        Console.Clear();
                        Console.SetCursorPosition(position.x, position.y);
                        Console.WriteLine("█");
                    }
                } while (true);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3244976/is-is-possible-to-programmatically-clear-the-console-history

Comment: doesn't work on ubuntu

Comment: my error : "is only supported on 'windows'.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by creating a new console every time you reset the position by using [Console Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-functions). Detach the current console with [FreeConsole](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/freeconsole?redirectedfrom=MSDN) and then create a new console using [AllocConsole](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/allocconsole).

Comment: doesn't work on ubuntu

Comment: "is only supported on 'windows'. - my error

Comment: Oh that's why this is happening at the first place. I ran your code and it works as intended on my windows machine.